# c++ cin only boolean(0,1)

Tags: c++, boolean

I wish to achieve to limit user on only 0 or 1 when program asking for boolean variable.
I'we tried to do so, but it doesn't work. It still keep asking me for typing in.

```
bool ele;
do{ 
    cout << "Elektro:\t"; 
    cin >> ele; 
    if (cin && ele == 0 && ele == 1) break;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Neveljaven vnos!" << endl;
}while(true);
```

Comment: How can `ele` equal both 0 and 1? Is this program meant for a quantum computer?

Comment: jrok's answer is more helpful. Please, change your accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As chris points out, you want to do `if (cin && (ele == 0 || ele == 1)) break;`

Comment: you are welcome! btw since you are reading `cin` into a bool, im not sure what would happen if you enter any other input other than 0/1. you might want to check it.

Comment: yea if i enter number it works ok. But when i press char..."s" for an example it gives me infinite loop...

Answer (score 6):

The good news is, that `operator>>` for `bool` by default allows only `'0'` or `'1'` as valid input. That means you don't need to explicitly check the value after read - if stream state is ok, so is your `bool`:

```
bool ele;
if (!(cin >> ele)) {
    // error;
}
```

The reason you're getting an infinite loop when you enter something like `"cvdsavd"` is that you only clear the error flags, but don't get rid of the bad charaters. So your loop keeps trying but never can get a valid input. You need to get rid of the garbage:

```
bool ele;
while (!(std::cin >> ele)) {
    std::cout << "Neveljaven vnos!\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

[Reference for `ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). You also need to include `<limits>` for `numeric_limits` template.

Lp :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that :

```
if (cin && ele == 0 && ele == 1) break;
```

because its always false because ele cant be in same time 1 or  0 ... It can be only one of this figures.

```
if(ele == 0 || ele == 1) break;
```